# Laravel Users and other Relationship Tables

Tags: php, laravel

Good day,  I just want to ask if my approach in database design in laravel is kind of okay. I'm kind of a novice on this

1. After the user registering to the site. His main information will be stored on the `users` table that contains mainly of his `name`, `email`, `password`, `role_id` and a `confirmed` column that is boolean value. The confirmed column just is set to zero as default that means that the admin has to approve that application in order for that to be changed to 1.
2. After the admin has approved the application of that specific user based on his/her roles. My approach is that querying to the `users` table based on his/her role like Select * from users where role_id = '2' and confirmed = '0' that means querying the table for those users who have the role_id of 2 and is not yet confirmed.
3. After the user has been confirmed by the admin. After he clicks the Approve option. The specific user can now log on to the site and can now enter his/her details in the `user_details` table.

I just want to ask if this is correct. Or if you have any ER diagram that I can use for help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds fine, but to be completely honest all of this depends on what you're trying to achieve. Don't overthink it. Build it, use it, see if it makes sense and make changes if necessary.